# Cannot find a file on localhost. 404 Not Found

Tags: php, apache2

```
danko@danko-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo service apache2 status
* apache2 is running

danko@danko-VirtualBox ~ $ php --version
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) (built: May 19 2016 19:05:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

danko@danko-VirtualBox ~ $ cd /var/www
danko@danko-VirtualBox /var/www $ cat < testphp.php
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But request in web browser (http://localhost/testphp.php) returns me, "The requested URL /testphp.php was not found on this server."

What's wrong?

Comment: Wrong path (the path served by Apache is /var/www/html instead of /var/www) ? Wrong permissions on file (Apache process doesn't have permissions to read the file) ? Also, you use a VM, localhost inside VirtualBox is not the same as localhost in host OS.

Comment: We get these questions often enough and every time, it is a path issue. You are not looking in the right place. Check the configuration of your web server / site to know where to look. Cheers!!

Comment: Yeah. Wrong path. With /var/www/html it works ok. Thank you.

Comment: I'm closing this because you indicate you were looking in the wrong directory.  This is not going to help other users with a similar error message.

Answer (score 1):

Set DocumentRoot value to "/var/www" which is the path your PHP script is in.

If you have a virtual host entry matching either localhost or the IP address of localhost on your machine then set DocumentRoot value in that virtual host block to "/var/www".

Then restart apache.

See details for DocumentRoot here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html